# Not getting push notification from push to server-side

Tags: php, google-cloud-messaging

I  push message from server side via php code, total I have 6 android device, when I push a message from via my php script then I got below response, I got notification in 4 device but in 2 did't got any notification, I see "success":6, Also those two android device id print in  result JSON response, and "canonical_ids":2 
PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php 
$registatoin_ids = array("XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX")
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' );
                    $message    = array("notification_status"=>1,"message"=>"Hello Android");   // Response for android

                    $fields = array
                    (
                        'registration_ids'  =>  $registatoin_ids,
                        'data'              =>  array( "price" => $message )
                    );
                    $headers = array
                    (
                        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
                    $result = curl_exec($ch );
                    curl_close( $ch );
                    echo $result;
?>
```

Response:

```
{
"multicast_id": 5091283388403222000,
"success": 6,
"failure": 0,
"canonical_ids": 2,
"results": [
    {
        "registration_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "message_id": "0:1439532747953065%12153c37f9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
        "registration_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "message_id": "0:1439532747954730%12153c37f9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
        "message_id": "0:1439532747954278%12153c37f9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
        "message_id": "0:1439532747963956%12153c37f9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
        "message_id": "0:1439532747953665%12153c37f9fd7ecd"
    },
    {
        "message_id": "0:1439532747954836%12153c37f9fd7ecd"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: First of all, Be more descriptive about the problem and tag relevently. 
Coming to the issue, Its device's problem, assuming you are running same code on all. As there is no error response from google.

Comment: Consider that we have **absolutely no idea** what kind of "device" or "server" or "push" system you're talking about. This needs a ton more clarification before anyone is able to say anything about it.

Comment: Hi Deceze thenk you for replay, can you please review my code. and hope you will give me again reply thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two devices with the Canonical Ids have replaced their old registration ID with a new one. The Canonical Id is this new one, which you should use for sending notifications in future requests.

From the official docs:

> [...] A canonical registration ID is the registration token of the last registration requested by the client app . This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the device.
>
> If you try to send a message using an old registration token, **GCM will process the request as usual**, but it will include the canonical ID in the registration_id field of the response. *(This is why is shows "success" for all your devices)* Make sure to replace the registration token stored in your server with this canonical ID, as **eventually the old registration token will stop working**.

So normally if you try to send the notification again with the two new IDs the devices should receive the notification as usual.

Comment: Thank you so much s.schmid,   My issue is solve now, I was change GMC id.

Comment: @RajuDudhrejiya if your issue is solved, please accept the answer so the question is marked as closed.